# Every terminal I open starts with this code, how can I stop this?

Tags: command-line, echo

every time I open up a terminal it starts with this.

```
export PATH="/home/name/.rbenv/shims:${PATH}"
export RBENV_SHELL=bash
source '/home/name/.rbenv/libexec/../completions/rbenv.bash'
command rbenv rehash 2>/dev/null
rbenv() {
  local command
  command="${1:-}"
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    shift
  fi

  case "$command" in
  rehash|shell)
    eval "$(rbenv "sh-$command" "$@")";;
  *)
    command rbenv "$command" "$@";;
  esac
}
export PATH="/home/name/.rbenv/shims:${PATH}"
export RBENV_SHELL=bash
source '/home/name/.rbenv/libexec/../completions/rbenv.bash'
command rbenv rehash 2>/dev/null
rbenv() {
  local command
  command="${1:-}"
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    shift
  fi

  case "$command" in
  rehash|shell)
    eval "$(rbenv "sh-$command" "$@")";;
  *)
    command rbenv "$command" "$@";;
  esac
}
name@Laptop:~$
```

I don't know if its an error msg or just some echo from some file, and would like to know why is it echoing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably something went wrong with (an installer) editing your `~/.bashrc`. You may want to edit it yourself or "reset" via `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: One can also check the differences using `diff -u /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc` or revert it interactively using `meld /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc` (GUI) or `vimdiff` (CLI).